# Concurrency issue in database operations in vertx

Tags: java, hsqldb, vert.x

I have to `insert` two attributes into a `table`(device_id, timestamp) but before this, I have to delete previous day's records and perform select count to get total count of records from the table.
Based on the count value, data will be inserted in the table.
I have a total of 3 queries which works fine for single user testing but if run a concurrency test with 10 users or more, my code is breaking.
I am using `hsqldb` and `vertx jdbc client.`
Is there a way to merge all three queries?
The queries are :

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE timestamp <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE device_id = ?
INSERT into table_name(device_id,timestamp) values (?,?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set auto-commit to false and commit after the last statement.

If the database transaction control is the default LOCKS mode, you will not get any inconsistency, because the table is locked by the DELETE statement until the commit.

If you have changed the transaction control to MVCC, then it depends on the way you use the COUNT in the INSERT statement.